# Koa-router not nesting

Tags: node.js, koa

```
const router2 = new KoaRouter();
router2.get(`/test`, async function(ctx, next) {
    ctx.body = 'api test';
});

const router = new KoaRouter();
router.get(`/1`, router2.routes(), router2.allowedMethods());
router.get(`/test`, async function(ctx, next) {
    ctx.body = 'test';
});
```

`127.0.0.1:300/test` works

`127.0.0.1:300/1/test` does not work

I can't see the problem?

Comment: I think it should be `router.use('/1', async function(ctx, next) {
    ctx.body = 'test';
});`

Comment: check this for more info https://github.com/alexmingoia/koa-router#nested-routers

Comment: @DeendayalGarg I've looked at that, I would however like to not write the full path in the lower router. I'd like it to be more "module" if you get what I mean.

Comment: You are not writing the full path. its just that when you use nested route you need to use `router.use` instead of `router.get`.

Comment: @DeendayalGarg Ahh correct! Post an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you are using nested routes you need to use `router.use` instead of `router.get`.